# How to set role based Kibana Dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am creating dashboards in `Kibana` based on `Amazon's ES Cluster` data. But I want to be able restrict the display of dashboard to certain user groups. Is it possible at `Kibana` or `ES Cluster` layer to be able to have some IAM role, thus the user logging into `Kibana` dashboard will see only permitted dashboards.

P.S: I am not using Elastic company's Kibana, I am using the Kibana that comes embedded with the AWS ES Cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that particular scenario is an option right now. But that is supported by the [OpenDistro version](https://discuss.opendistrocommunity.dev/t/limit-access-to-dashboards/266/2) by using tenants.

When the Elasticsearch service adds multi-tenant, your use case should be supported.

You could always install OpenDistro yourself if that feature is a must for you right now, and migrate to the hosted service once they are on par for this particular feature.